# select multiple nth values in grouping with conditional aggregate - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by, aggregate

i've got a pd.DataFrame with four columns

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2] 
                      , 'A':['H','H','E','E','H','E','E','H','H']
                      , 'B':[4,5,2,7,6,1,3,1,0]
                      , 'C':['M','D','M','D','M','M','M','D','D']})

   id  A  B  C
0   1  H  4  M
1   1  H  5  D
2   1  E  2  M
3   1  E  7  D
4   1  H  6  M
5   2  E  1  M
6   2  E  3  M
7   2  H  1  D
8   2  H  0  D
```

I'd like to group by id and get the value of B for the nth (let's say second) occurrence of A = 'H' for each id in agg_B1 and value of B for the nth (let's say first) occurrence of C='M':

```
desired output:
   id  agg_B1  agg_B2
0   1      5      4  
1   2      0      1

desired_output = df.groupby('id').agg(
      agg_B1= ('B',lambda x:x[df.loc[x.index].loc[df.A== 'H'][1]])
   ,  agg_B2= ('B',lambda x:x[df.loc[x.index].loc[df.C== 'M'][0]])

    ).reset_index()

TypeError: Indexing a Series with DataFrame is not supported, use the appropriate DataFrame column
```

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong with the indexing.

---

Edit: if possible, I'd like to use aggregate with lambda function, because there are multiple aggregate outputs of other sorts that I'd like to extract at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is possible change if need [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
desired_output = df.groupby('id').agg(
      agg_B1= ('B',lambda x:x[df.loc[x.index, 'A']== 'H'].iat[1]),
      agg_B2= ('B',lambda x:x[df.loc[x.index, 'C']== 'M'].iat[0])
    ).reset_index()


print (desired_output)
   id  agg_B1  agg_B2
0   1       5       4
1   2       0       1
```

But if performance is important and also not sure if always exist second value matched `H` for first condition I suggest processing each condition separately and last add to original aggregated values:

```
#some sample aggregations
df0 = df.groupby('id').agg({'B':'sum', 'C':'last'})

df1 = df[df['A'].eq('H')].groupby("id")['B'].nth(1).rename('agg_B1')
df2 = df[df['C'].eq('M')].groupby("id")['B'].first().rename('agg_B2')

desired_output = pd.concat([df0, df1, df2], axis=1)
print (desired_output)
     B  C  agg_B1  agg_B2
id                       
1   24  M       5       4
2    5  D       0       1
```

EDIT1: If need [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) is possible test if failed indexing and then add missing value:

```
#for second value in sample working nice
def f1(x):
    try:
        return x[df.loc[x.index, 'A']== 'H'].iat[1]
    except:
        return np.nan

desired_output = df.groupby('id').agg(
      agg_B1= ('B',f1),
      agg_B2= ('B',lambda x:x[df.loc[x.index, 'C']== 'M'].iat[0])
    ).reset_index()

print (desired_output)
   id  agg_B1  agg_B2
0   1       5       4
1   2       0       1
```

```
#third value not exist so added missing value NaN
def f1(x):
    try:
        return x[df.loc[x.index, 'A']== 'H'].iat[2]
    except:
        return np.nan

desired_output = df.groupby('id').agg(
      agg_B1= ('B',f1),
      agg_B2= ('B',lambda x:x[df.loc[x.index, 'C']== 'M'].iat[0])
    ).reset_index()

print (desired_output)
   id  agg_B1  agg_B2
0   1     6.0       4
1   2     NaN       1
```

What working same like:

```
df1 = df[df['A'].eq('H')].groupby("id")['B'].nth(2).rename('agg_B1')
df2 = df[df['C'].eq('M')].groupby("id")['B'].first().rename('agg_B2')

desired_output = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print (desired_output)
    agg_B1  agg_B2
id                
1      6.0       4
2      NaN       1
```

Comment: wow, i really got the indexing messed up! Thanks so much, that's exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @Ankhnesmerira - I add some edits, please test in real data if working correct (because also solution failed if not exist second value of group for first `.iat[1]`)

Comment: so, in my real dataset this fails (i'm only using first occurances) with 
"IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0." How do I make sure i just get Null for those that don't have any occurrence instead of an error message?

Comment: @Ankhnesmerira - just added edit for this situtation.

Answer (score 2):

Filter for rows where `A` equals `H`, then grab the second row with the [nth](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) function :

```
df.query("A=='H'").groupby("id").nth(1)

    A   B
id      
1   H   5
2   H   0
```

Python works on a zero based notation, so row 2 will be `nth(1)`

Comment: Thanks for this solution. this works but my issue is that i actually would like to use aggregate. Because there are more than one output that i'm interested in. i guess i oversimplified my problem in the example. What if I waned another aggregate but for A=='E' in the same aggregation operation? with the initial querying this would not be possible. How can i use it in an aggregate?

Comment: sure thing, I've edited the question, because the original simplified question wasn't really my problem. <:}

Comment: Lol no worries. Glad someone got to solve it already